# What is the meaning of 가다듬어? Naver dictionary wasn't much help

Tags: meaning, single-word-request

I'm trying to find the meaning of 가다듬어, but [naver dictionary](http://dic.naver.com/search.nhn?dicQuery=%EA%B0%80%EB%8B%A4%EB%93%AC%EC%96%B4&x=0&y=0&query=%EA%B0%80%EB%8B%A4%EB%93%AC%EC%96%B4&target=dic&ie=utf8&query_utf=&isOnlyViewEE=) wasn't being much help as it said 'straighten' but that didn't really fit with the sentence I had, and the other examples seemed to suggest 'to clear'.  So I'm wondering what exactly is the usage of it?

Comment: Can you provide the sentence where you saw it?

Comment: I'm at work right now but I can get it when I go home for lunch! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [국립국어원학습사전](http://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/mainAction?nation=eng) has more complete definitions for [가다듬다](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?wordMatchFlag=N&mainSearchWord=%EA%B0%80%EB%8B%A4%EB%93%AC%EC%96%B4&currentPage=1&sort=W&searchType=W&proverbType=&exaType=&ParaWordNo=28117&nation=eng&nationCode=6&viewType=A&blockCount=10&viewTypes=on):

1. brace; pull oneself together
   마음이나 정신 등을 바로잡다.
   To collect one's mind, spirit, etc. together.
2. adjust oneself
   몸가짐이나 자세 등을 단정하게 정리하다.
   To straighten one's conduct, posture, etc.
3. clear; adjust
   목청이나 호흡 등을 고르게 조절하다.
   To clear one's throat or adjust one's breath.
4. set in good order
   흐트러진 대열이나 조직 등을 정리하여 싸울 준비를 하다.
   To prepare to fight by adjusting a line, organization, etc.

and also has lots of [examples](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?wordMatchFlag=N&mainSearchWord=%EA%B0%80%EB%8B%A4%EB%93%AC%EC%96%B4&currentPage=1&sort=W&searchType=W&proverbType=&exaType=&ParaWordNo=28117&nation=eng&nationCode=6&viewType=A&blockCount=10&viewTypes=on).